# Laravel doesn't read config in .env file

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

Laravel doesn't read config in env, so env('APP_KEY') always returns NULL. I also use:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:cache
```

but it doesn't have any effect. Do you have any solutions to fix? First time, I could fix by using 2 command above, but now I can't.

Comment: so did you tried `php artisan key:generate` first

Comment: is this happening when you first installed laravel or when you took it over from another person? Because if its the second you need to generate a key yourself

Comment: I have generated key several times. That isn't first time I install, I have run it before this error occurred

Comment: Maybe you (server) have not enough permissions for .env file?

Comment: php artisan key:generate can change key in env file, and I run on Windows

Comment: Try to use PHP's built in getenv() function to check if it works

Comment: @lifekent it return bool(false)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

then:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and make sure that you have permissions to run these commands, or you can simply run them with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you registered the variable in the config/services.php file, make sure to include the word **services** in your viariable configuration
path when calling it.

Example:

```
config('services.myApp.key');
```